# Existing very detailed derivation of sum of squares error for split-plot ANOVA?

Tags: anova, split-plot

Since a few years i'm trying to group all very detailed derivations of all (very common) existing ANOVA in a document. For some it's a real pain in the a** to do this work.

Now i'm near an intellectual suicide as i want to do it for the split-plot ANOVA (i will keep the split-split plot ANOVA for the next decade if i'm still alive...).

I have however tried this last 8 months to found a paper, book, document (PDF or whatever) with a very detailed derivation but without success :-(

So i come to you to know if some of you know where to find or have on their computer the detailed SSE decomposition of the split-plot ANOVA.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this answered with all the gory details in Hinkelmann & Kempthorne: "Design and Analysis of Experiments, Volume 1" (second edition). That is a very complete treatment.

So far this is an answer stub, I will come back for details and examples.

Comment: Sadly i know this book. And it is far of what can be we can qualify of "detailed developments". For example for the Latin Square Design (LSD) there is only one half page of maths when in reality you need 6 pages to write down the details.

Comment: Ok I will come back and try to write out the details. But now I am travelling on vacation.

Comment: Ok. Let me know when you are back. I will share with you the LaTeX source document with the few pages i have written so far.

Enjoy your vacation!